# can't find import go-gtk

Tags: go, goinstall

I've been playing around with Google Go, I love the power behind it and decided to try out some libraries. I tried using goinstall to install github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk but when I try to compile an example I'm getting:

```
can't find import: github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk
```

I've heard that others have problems with goinstall, is there anything I can do to fix this? I also saw that some people fixed this by putting the path as something like github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk/gtk.so but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
go install github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk
```

and it will download and install this library in $GOPATH/src

Comment: Unfortunately, some sort of wizardry is needed to tell go to look in `$GOPATH/src` for the package `gtk` when a program includes `import "gtk"`

Comment: `$ go install github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk
can't load package: package github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk: cannot find package "github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk" in any of:
 /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gtk (from $GOROOT)
 ($GOPATH not set)
` - not working

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to install necessary packages

```
go get github.com/mattn/go-gtk
```